# Two columns with pagebreak

Tags: tables, columns

For a comparison I am doing I need two columns. Each column is specific to the objects being compared. I want it to look like the image where each column is able to continue to the next page.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Concerning the two-column layout here,  the package `paracol` could help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Welcome to TeX.SE. Concerning the two-column layout here, the package paracol could help here – Christian Hupfer

The [paracol package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol) solved the problem. Thanks Christian!

http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/paracol/paracol-man.pdf